# Certificate pinning in Alamofire not working

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, ssl-certificate, alamofire

I've added a .der certificate to my project, which is recognised by `ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle()`. I'm now creating a Manager which is then used to make API calls:

```
private class func manager() -> Alamofire.Manager {
    let certificates = ServerTrustPolicy.PinCertificates(
        certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle(),
        validateCertificateChain: true,
        validateHost: true
    )

    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "api.oursite.com": certificates
    ]

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    let manager = Alamofire.Manager(
        configuration: configuration,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )

    return manager
}
```

Before this, it was just using `Alamofire.request(...`, and those requests were working perfectly fine, but now it's giving me an error on every call:

`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"`

Am I setting up the manager incorrectly? Perhaps my certificate was created incorrectly, and that's causing this to not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure that your `manager` not deallocated in short time after request. Make it as stored property in custom Manager class for example.